# Fragment update view in view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am using view pager which is having 3 fragments

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private static final String TAG="ViewPageAdapter";
    private final int PAGES = 3;
    private String[] title = new String[]{"Frag1",
            "Frag2", "Frag2"};

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "position is " + position);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Frag1();
            case 1:
                return new Frag2();
            case 2:
                return new Frag3();
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "The item position should be less or equal to:" + PAGES);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGES;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return title[position];
    }

}
```

I am setting view pager from main activity:

```
viewPageAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(onPageChangeListener);
viewPager.setAdapter(viewPageAdapter);
```

When i execute     viewPageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
or viewPager.setAdapter(viewPageAdapter); method to recreate fragments the activity is getting destroyed.don't know what causing the issue.
I checked many solution nothing worked.
[ViewPager PagerAdapter not updating the View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view)

[Update ViewPager dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849552/update-viewpager-dynamically)

I am asking another problem because which is related to above question.
The problem which is described in link
[ViewPager onPageSelected for first page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154870/viewpager-onpageselected-for-first-page)
where i am not able to get first page tab title on load.i am using **android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip**

Please help me in getting solved. Wasted my whole day to get rid of this :(

Comment: What kind of error you receive in logCat?

Comment: I am getting skipped xx frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.But i am doing nothing in main thread.

Comment: It's not what i meant... We need a stackTrace of error that caused activities crushing.

Comment: There is no error coming in verbose. i checked.

Comment: Maybe it caused by PagerTabStrip... Try to remove it to check it)